# Lisp, cons and (number . number) difference

Tags: lisp, quote, cons

What is the difference between

```
(cons 2  3)
```

and

```
'(2 . 3)
```

in Lisp?

Comment: Is that a period or a comma in the second expression?

Comment: @David: wondered if it's possible to change your answer pick. I like danlei's better than mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'(2 . 3)` is a dotted pair.

`(cons 2 3)` creates a dotted pair too. So these should evaluate to the same thing.

So one is a literal for a dotted pair, the other one creates a dotted pair.

Comment: Actually there is a difference in that `cons` would produce a setf-able place and `quote` would produce a constant value which you should not modify.

Answer (score 10):

They are not exactly the same, even though they evaluate to the same values in the REPL. Consider these examples, in which cons cells are modified destructively:

```
TEST> (defun literal-cons ()
        (let ((cons '(1 . 2)))
          (incf (cdr cons))
          cons))
LITERAL-CONS
TEST> (literal-cons)
(1 . 3)
TEST> (literal-cons)
(1 . 4)
TEST> (literal-cons)
(1 . 5)
```

Compared to this:

```
TEST> (defun non-literal-cons ()
        (let ((cons (cons 1 2)))
          (incf (cdr cons))
          cons))
NON-LITERAL-CONS
TEST> (non-literal-cons)
(1 . 3)
TEST> (non-literal-cons)
(1 . 3)
```

In the first version, you are changing the [literal](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_l.htm#literal) cons cell in the code itself (thus, this is self-modifying code). In the second version, the cons cell is not literal. It is produced every time the code is called, and only this fresh cons cell will be changed.

```
TEST> (function-lambda-expression #'literal-cons)
(LAMBDA NIL
  (DECLARE (CCL::GLOBAL-FUNCTION-NAME LITERAL-CONS))
  (BLOCK LITERAL-CONS (LET ((CONS '(1 . 5))) (INCF (CDR CONS)) CONS))) ;; notice the '(1 . 5)
NIL
LITERAL-CONS
```

Since this can lead to subtle bugs when using destructive operations, one should be careful with such literal objects in code. This also affects list literals (`'(1 2 3)` vs. `(list 1 2 3)`), which are built from cons cells.

From the [HyperSpec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_l.htm#literal):

> literal adj. (of an object) referenced directly in a program rather
>   than being computed by the program; that is, appearing as data in a
>   quote form, or, if the object is a self-evaluating object, appearing
>   as unquoted data. ``In the form (cons "one" '("two")), the expressions
>   "one", ("two"), and "two" are literal objects.''

Comment: Your `literal-cons` function's behavior must be specific to your implementation. On SBCL, I get the results as your `non-literal-cons`. This is curious enough that I opened a new question about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20342793/is-this-an-implementation-specific-behavior

Comment: @OpenLearner Right;  the consequences of modifying literal data are undefined by the standard.  Anything could happen.  I think the example shown in this answer is common, but SBCL does seem to be doing something interesting here…

Answer (score 2):

Both are objects with similar structures. That is, they're both cons cells, with 2 in the CAR position and 3 in the CDR position.

The main difference between them is that '(2 . 3) is a constant and (cons 2 3) generates a new cons cell. The distinction between these should become evident if you take two (similar-looking) functions as per below:

```
(defun a () 
  (let ((v (cons 2 3))) 
   (incf (car v))
   v)

(defun b () 
  (let ((v '(2 . 3))) 
   (incf (car v))
   v)
```

Quite a few implementations will return '(3 . 3) '(4 . 3) and so on as you keep calling b.

Answer (score 0):

`(1 . 2)` is the s-expression syntax for a `cons` cell. The cons cell has 1 as the `car` and 2 as the `cdr`.

`'(1 . 2)` with the quote character in front is a short notation for `(quote (1 . 2))`. The `quote` instructs the evaluator to not (!) evaluate the form it encloses and to just return it as it is. The value of this quoted form is just the form itself. `quote` says: do not evaluate. In Common Lisp this can be considered to be constant literal data.

`(cons 1 2)` is a Lisp form which has the function `cons` in front and two arguments: 1 and 2. If we evaluate this form, the function `cons` gets called with the argument 1 and 2. `cons` returns by definition a new cons cell with its arguments as the `car` and `cdr`. So `(cons 1 2)` returns a fresh new cons cell whenever we evaluate it.

Answer (score 0):

they are not the same and are the same.

the simbol quote (') is  a function that says: "create this list whithout evaluating this."
      example: '(* 2 2 ) ; It's going to create the list ( * 2 2 )
               (list (* 2 2)  ; It's going to create (4) because the list is evaluated.

the function cons create associated pairs and just this.
Example: (cons (a b c) (1 2 3) ) ;create (a b c . 1 2 3)
         (cons a (1 2 3 4) )     ;create (a. 1 2 3 4)

The two functions you used do the same thing on this case, but using diferents ways to do it.
because quote (') just create the list in front of the simbol quote ('), and the cons function just create the associated pair with the "itens" thar you gave to the function.