# Elisp: cannot grasp effect of setq and sort

Tags: elisp

When evaluating the following code in Emacs, I get (2 3) as the final value of x. I'd expect (1 2 3). What am I missing?

```
(setq x '(2 1 3))
(sort x '<)
x
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you read `sort`'s documentation, you will find that it *returns* the sorted list, and the input list is *modified* by side effects. It does not say that the argument list will contain the sorted result -- It is just somehow modified by the sorting algorithm. Or, to put it shortly: `sort` is *destructive*.

So, you'll want to bind/assign `sort`'s return value:

```
elisp> (setq x '(2 1 3))
(2 1 3)

elisp> (setq x (sort x '<))
(1 2 3)

elisp> x
(1 2 3)
```

Comment: Also, note that modifying literals destructively may have consequences you don't expect. (See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865142/lisp-cons-and-number-number-difference/6866155#6866155, which is about CL but applies to Emacs-Lisp, too)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much experience with elisp, but it is behaving correctly due to the implementation with car and cdr. Check http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/elisp/html_node/Rearrangement.html#Rearrangement

Comment: I guess I was unclear. I do not mean (last x), but the final value of x.