# Setting global variable reverts to last value

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm getting some strange behavior when I try to set a global parameter within a method.

```
(defparameter *global-var-1* nil)

(defun method1 ()
   (setf *global-var-1* '())
   (format t "~a~%" *global-var-1*)

   ...
   (loop
      ...

      (setf *global-var-1* '(a))
      (format t "~a~%" *global-var-1*)

      (nconc *global-var-1* (list '(b c))))
```

In the above code, when I call method1, the first format statement always prints `nil` as expected. The second format statement prints `(A)` the first time method1 is called, but the second time it prints `(A (B C))`. The third time `(A (B C) (B C))` and so on. Instead of setting `*global-var-1*` to `(A)`, setf seems to be setting it to the previous known value. What am I doing wrong? BTW, I was setting `*global-var-1` to `(A)` because `nconc` won't work with an empty list. I remove `(A)` later on before exiting method1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course `nconc` works with empty lists, but you must always assign its return value, like this:

```
CL-USER> (defparameter *x* nil)
*X*
CL-USER> (setq *x* (nconc *x* (list 'a)))
(A)
CL-USER> *x*
(A)
```

Then, your problem is solved by not using literal lists:

```
CL-USER> (defparameter *x* nil)
*X*
CL-USER> (defun foo ()
           (setf *x* nil)
           (dotimes (n 3)
             (progn (setf *x* (list 'a))
                    (format t "~a~%" *x*)
                    (setf *x* (nconc *x* (list (list 'b 'c)))))))
FOO
CL-USER> (foo)
(A)
(A)
(A)
```

You should always be careful when using destructive operations, and be aware of the implications of using them with literal expressions. In your code, `nconc` destructively modified the `cdr` of your `'(a)` list literal, which results in the behavior you observed. (You could always use `append` to get around this, if you're not optimizing.)

You might also be interested in my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865142/lisp-cons-and-number-number-difference/6866155#6866155) about this topic.

Comment: Thanks. I was using **append** and I wanted to make the code a little faster, hence the **nconc**. Still new to lisp and I keep forgetting that what looks like a literal in c or java is a symbol in lisp with such consequences.