# Modifying a list passed as a parameter gives different results in SBCL and CLISP

Tags: common-lisp

Can someone explain why I get different results for the following simple program with sbcl and clisp? Is what I am doing undefined by the language, or is one of the two lisp interpreters wrong?

```
; Modify the car of the passed-in list
(defun modify (a) (setf (car a) 123))

; Create a list and print car before and after calling modify
(defun testit () (let ((a '(0)))
                   (print (car a))
                   (modify a)
                   (print (car a))))
(testit)
```

SBCL (version 1.0.51) produces:

```
0 
0
```

CLISP (version 2.49) produces (what I would expect):

```
0 
123
```

Comment: Perhaps it has to do with the fact that you are modifying a literal list. Try changing it to `let ((a (cons 0 nil)))`

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8962909/why-does-this-function-return-a-different-value-every-time/8963438

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Seth's and Vsevolod's comments in that this behavior is due to your modification of literal data. Try using `(list 0)` instead of `'(0)`. Questions relating to this come up relatively frequently, so I'll quote the [HyperSpec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/index.htm) here.

[3.7.1 Modification of Literal Objects](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/03_ga.htm):

> The consequences are undefined if literal objects are destructively
>   modified.

The [definition of "literal"](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/26_glo_l.htm#literal):

> literal adj. (of an object) referenced directly in a program rather
>   than being computed by the program; that is, appearing as data in a
>   quote form, or, if the object is a self-evaluating object, appearing
>   as unquoted data. ``In the form (cons "one" '("two")), the expressions
>   "one", ("two"), and "two" are literal objects.''

Note that often (in many implementations), if you modify literal values, you'll really modify them in the code itself – writing *self modifying code*. Your example code will not work as you expect.

Your example code in CCL:

```
CL-USER> (defun modify (a) (setf (car a) 123))
MODIFY
CL-USER> (defun testit ()
           (let ((a '(0)))
             (print (car a))
             (modify a)
             (print (car a))))
TESTIT
CL-USER> (testit)

0 
123 
123
CL-USER> (testit)

123 
123 
123
```

Take a look at the second evaluation of `testit`, where the `let` itself really already contains the modified value, thus the first `print` also yields `123`.

Also see: [Lisp, cons and (number . number) difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865142/lisp-cons-and-number-number-difference/6866155#6866155), where I explained this in more detail, or the question linked in Vsevolod's comment above.

Comment: Thanks. Until now I was treating the literal list as analogous to an initializer in C++. For example, std::pair<int, int>(1, 2) or int a[] = {1, 2, 3}. But I see now, in my original example, that '(0) is not an initializer, but it is the actual list.